# How often should I delete & save to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm writing an application where it is necessary to talk to Core Data quite often. I'm concerned with both my application and core data performance due to frequent access.

Basically on the main screen, I will do the following actions when user press a button on the UI. Fetch from core data -> Delete fetched object in Core Data-> Add to Core Data

In the design of my application, the user may perform the button press multiple times (once every 3secs), and it will perform the above action quite often. I am also required to remember what was last saved when user exits the app.

Going by such design, how should I handle the data? Will there be any concern with such design flow?

Comment: Why do you need to delete and then add to the persistence store everytime? It's a feature?

Comment: I need to remember what was generated on button event click if user exits the application. It's not necessary to save everytime on button clicked, or I could do it on applicationWillTerminate, but I'm afraid to lose this information if event is not called.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Don't worry about the performance unless you have actually observed a performance issue. Core Data is pretty fast, you may not have a problem.

Comment: Halfway through what I've described above. But while being more into it, I'm starting to feel uneasy with the approach I'm working towards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work fine, unless the objects that you save are very big, or extremely complex e.g. have many relationships. Of course it also depends on what else is going on in your app simultaneously, like network traffic, other file operations etc.

Just be sure to use a parent/child context combination to perform the actual file operation on a background queue.

One way to minimize the number of file operations would also be to only save to your (in-memory) working context when the user taps the button and only persist to disk (through the private context) every once in a while, eg when the user leaves the current screen or the app goes to the background. The only downside to this is that you could lose data when your app crashes before the disk operation.

** I just edited this answer to make it clear that the private context used for saving to disk should be the parent of your working context

Answer (score 1):

Apple documentation addresses the performance issue [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html). You can read more on the given link

> If you are using the SQLite store, you can use a fetch limit to minimize the working set of managed objects in memory and so improve
>   the performance of your application.
>
> If you need to retrieve many objects, you can make your application
>   appear more responsive by executing multiple fetches. In the first
>   fetch, you retrieve a comparatively small number of objects—for
>   example, 100—and populate the user interface with these objects. You
>   then execute subsequent fetches to retrieve the complete result set
>   via the fetchOffset method.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation!

Answer (score -1):

Follow this Simple Steps whenever you're in doubt if you're overdoing with Core Data or not.

> ### Simple Core Data implementation.
>
> 1. Get Data From the User
> 2. Put it in Context
> 3. Validate Context
>
>    - If Validation Successful Go to Step 4.
>    - If Validation Failed Go to Step 6.
> 4. Save Context
> 5. Fetch Context and Show it to the User
>
>    - If User wants to delete the Data go to Step 6
>    - If User Updates the Data Go to Step 2
>    - If User doesn't interact with Data than iterate over Step 5
> 6. Delete Context

Cheers!